# Is it possible to develop plugins for iOS and Android mail apps?

Tags: android, ios, email

I want to develop a plugin with similar requirements to the common "Send Later" plugin. Basically I need to add another Send Button that triggers my app functionality.

Do iOS Mail and Android Gmail apps allow you to write plugins for them? In such case would it be possible to add a custom Send Button or a popup after the user clicks send?

Comment: Absolutely not for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do iOS Mail and Android Gmail apps allow you to write plugins for them?

A commenter indicates that the answer is "no" for iOS Mail.

The answer definitely is "no" for Gmail on Android. I am not aware of any Android email client that offers a plugin API.